# How do I use replace() to remove comma and None from string

Tags: javascript

How do I use `replace()` to remove comma from string.

```
 "{"segerity": 5,"designJroups": "AB3,EncKrodPvc", "segerity": 2}"
"{"segerity": 5,"designJroups": None, "segerity": 2}"
```

I am trying something like this

```
 const objRemove = ReplaceData.replace(/deviceGroups[^,]+"/g, '');
```

since I have `+`, the `replace()` method is removing till `"designJroups": "AB3,` I need to remove entire `"designJroups": "AB3,EncKrodPvc",`

expected result

```
"{"segerity": 5,"segerity": 2}"
"{"segerity": 5,"segerity": 2}"
```

Comment: Hope you aren't trying to use that as JSON. If so, you can't duplicate a property name in an object

Comment: It looks like the object `"{"segerity": 5,"designGroups": "AB3,EncKrodPvc", "segerity": 2}"` itself is a string, and you are merely trying to remove the key-value pair of all `deignGroups`. Try using the regular expression `/\"designJroups\":\ ?\".*\"\,/g`.

Comment: is there a way to replace two double quotes with only 1 for the value below         "designJroups": ""AB3,EncKrodPvc"" the "designJroups": should be as it is only quotes form the value should be removed.